# Find path of excel file in dll

Tags: excel, dll, path

I have a dll that needs to open an excel file but i cannot seem to create the path to the file. The excel file is a template that must be used to compare with an excel file that the user will browse for and open.

I have used this code previously when using an exe file for my application:

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Data\\BulkMaintenanceExample.xls");
```

but with a dll it does not seem to work. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following to get the assembly path:

```
var dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

or

```
//get the full location of the assembly with DaoTests in it 
string fullPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(DaoTests)).Location; 
string theDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName( fullPath );
```

or

```
string filePath = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath; 
return Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
```

Comment: To be honest i had forgotten to include the folder and excel file with the calling programs executable program. Managed to fix it that way. Thanks for the help though I tested your way and it works was well.